# Problem configuring openvrml-0.18.9

Tags: c++, configure, autoconf

Downloaded latest version from http://openvrml.org/

Working with Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (x86_64)

Tried to configure it without success:

```
alex@pc:~/Downloads/openvrml-0.18.9$ ./configure
...
checking for boost_thread-mt library... no
configure: error: in `/home/alex/Downloads/openvrml-0.18.9':
configure: error: libboost_thread-mt not found
See `config.log' for more details
```

Libraries seem to be properly installed:

```
alex@pc:~$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu | grep -E "boost_thread|boost_filesystem|boost_system"
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217692 ene 16  2014 libboost_filesystem.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       29 ene 16  2014 libboost_filesystem.so -> libboost_filesystem.so.1.55.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    88936 jun 21  2014 libboost_filesystem.so.1.54.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    88936 ene 16  2014 libboost_filesystem.so.1.55.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    49186 ene 16  2014 libboost_system.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       25 ene 16  2014 libboost_system.so -> libboost_system.so.1.55.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    14536 jun 21  2014 libboost_system.so.1.54.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    14536 ene 16  2014 libboost_system.so.1.55.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   200894 ene 16  2014 libboost_thread.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       25 ene 16  2014 libboost_thread.so -> libboost_thread.so.1.55.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    88632 jun 21  2014 libboost_thread.so.1.54.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    92728 ene 16  2014 libboost_thread.so.1.55.0
alex@pc:~$
```

Header files seem to be installed too:

```
alex@pc:~$ ls -l /usr/include/boost/thread.hpp 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 839 ene 16  2014 /usr/include/boost/thread.hpp
alex@pc:~$
```

Comment: If you compare the [Trusty filelist](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libboost-thread1.54-dev/filelist) versus the [Precise filelist](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/libboost-thread1.46-dev/filelist) for the underlying libboost_thread1.xy-dev package, it appears that the `-mt` suffix has been dropped. The openvrml ./configure script provides a BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX environment variable: running `BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX= ./configure` appears to find the library, but there is a further (undefined reference) error that results in the script failing at the same point.

Comment: ... try `BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX= LIBS=-lboost_system ./configure`